# How to have all sections unnumbered in org-mode with inheriting property?

Tags: org-mode

I would want to have all sections unnumbered. Instead to add the property

```
* Section Name
  :PROPERTIES:
  :UNNUMBERED: t
  :END:
```

to each subtree (which works well). I thought to use inheriting property in the top of the file as specified [in the documentation](https://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) :

```
#+PROPERTY: UNNUMBERED t
```

but this approach doesn't work. What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil
```

As for the `#+PROPERTY:` setting, I can reproduce the problem: I thought at first that turning `org-use-property-inheritance` on would do the job, but I cannot get inheritance to work in this context (with a `#+PROPERTY:` setting). It *does* work in the context of a top-level headline having the property and lower-level headlines inheriting it:

```
#+PROPERTY: UNNUMBERED t

* Section name foo
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:

** Section name baz

** Section name hunoz

* Section name bar
```

The first section and its subsections are unnumbered; the second section is numbered.

Whether inheritance should work with `#+PROPERTIES:` seems to me to be a reasonable question (or even a bug report) for the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).